# How to get all Strings in a specific class?

Tags: java, string, class, get

I am programming a Java program, and need to get all Strings in a specified class.

Actually I want them to be saved in an ArrayList. I already tried but I don't know how to do that.

For example, if I have the following Strings in my class:
public String chicken = "wing";
public String foo = "bar";

Then i want a method that will find all this Strings, and put them in an ArrayList!

Thank you :)

Thats what I tried:

```
        for(Field f : UUIDd.class.getFields()) {
    System.out.println("trying");
    if(f.getType().isAssignableFrom(String.class)) {
        String s = f.toString();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post what have you try...

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: first of all show your code

Comment: If you have tried something yet, show what you have tried and show where you are stuck.

Comment: So what have you tried? And can you give examples on the input and expected output? I assume you're after reflection but I can't be sure with the little information you provided.

Comment: @Freakey edit your question and post this,

Comment: What do you mean by "all Strings in a specified class"? Your question is unclear...

Comment: Ok, i posted what i tried.

Comment: I mean that I want to get all declared Strings in a class.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you want to get? "all declared Strings in a class" is not clear enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this way.

```
Field[] fields=UUIDd.class.getDeclaredFields(); // get all declared fields 
for(Field field:fields){
   if(field.getType().equals(String.class)){ // if it is a String field
     System.out.println(field.getName());
   }
}
```

You can get the value of the `Filed` too.

```
UUIDd uuiDd=new UUIDd();
Field[] fields= uuiDd.getClass().getDeclaredFields(); // get all declared fields
for(Field field:fields){
   if(field.getType().equals(String.class)){ // if it is a String field
      System.out.println("Variable name: "+field.getName());
      field.setAccessible(true);
      System.out.println("Variable value: "+field.get(uuiDd));
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how I could convert this Field to a String, so that I can get its value?

Comment: @Freakey what do you mean by convert? you mean cast `Field` to `String`? you want to take the value of the variable ?

Comment: Yes, thats what i want ^^

Comment: @Freakey you can have that in last part of my answer